# struts2 action redirecting to a div id in the same page jquery mobile style?

Tags: jquery-mobile, struts2

I'm new to both struts2 and jquery mobile, so please be patient with me.
What I want to do is the typical jquery mobile button that loads a different view located in the same .jsp file, like this:

```
<div data-role="page">
 <div data-role="content">
  <a data-role="button" href="someAction.action"> button </a>
 </div>
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="page2">
...
```

so that someAction does its stuff and then the page with id="page2" is shown instead of the previous page, just like it would happen if the code was like this:

```
<div data-role="page">
 <div data-role="content">
  <a data-role="button" href="#page2"> button </a>
 </div>
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="page2">
...
```

I'm not using the struts2 jquery mobile plugin because I read around here that it is better to keep jquery and struts2 separated... and because there is not much information available for learning that plugin anyway.

I'm guessing it must have something to do with the type of result returned by the action but I really cannot find the answer, I've been trying for a whole day now. Please help!.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know how struts work, but you can use `$.mobile.changePage("#page_id");` after executing the action.

Comment: You have probably misinformed about struts2 and jQuery, the only plugin that support Ajax in Struts tags via jQuery.

Comment: Omar: thx but I cannot do that with struts2
Roman: I finally decided to go without the single page approach. There is almost no information on struts2 jquery mobile plugin and I really cannot waste any time. But thx, maybe I am missinformed :S